# python print matched string, another string at nth line again starting the loop for finding string

Tags: python, string, enumerate

i have just started to learn python programming.
below is output file.

```
SERVER-XXX:
        IPADDR
        text1
        text2
        text3
    SERVER-yyy:
        IPADDR
        text3
        text1
        text2
    SERVER-zzz:
        IPADDR
        text1
        text3
        text2
```

1. I am reading line by line. firstly it will search for "Server*" and print
2. Then within SERVER another loop will start to search for another string text3 and print and Loop breaks.
3. then again 1st loop will search for another word matched SERVER*and so on.

i require the output as :

```
SERVER-XXX:
text3
SERVER-yyy:
text3
SERVER-zzz:
text3
```

below is the code which i have prepared

```
import re
f = open('dsp.txt', 'r')
for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    line=line.rstrip('\n')
    line=line.strip()
    print(i, line)
    if line.startswith("SERVER"):
        while i > 0:
            i=i+1
            print i
            if "text3" in line: # here i am not able to increment line.
                x= line[i]
                print ("%d" % line + /n + x)
                break
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: here `if "text3" in line:` is always false because the value of the `line` is all time 'SERVER'

Comment: But I do not understand where does those text3 from server-yyy and server-zzz comes from. Can you explain it better?

Comment: i have many consolidated data server details output. i need to segragate the servers having text3. text3 is just a string which is common in all servers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need two `for` loops for this. You just need to change the `search term` when one is found. Something like this:

```
look = 'SERVER'
tooglelook = lambda x: 'SERVER' if x == 'text3' else 'text3'
for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
    if look in line:
        print line
        look = tooglelook(look)
```

for your given sample input:

```
SERVER-XXX:
        IPADDR
        text1
        text2
        text3
    SERVER-yyy:
        IPADDR
        text3
        text1
        text2
    SERVER-zzz:
        IPADDR
        text1
        text3
        text2
```

produces this output

```
SERVER-XXX:
text3
SERVER-yyy:
text3
SERVER-zzz:
text3
```

Comment: thanks shaktiman. code works.I require to print server whole name also. so i added a code as `print line` . but if i want to print complete line containing text3. then.?

Comment: @Prayag I think `print line` should work fine for both 'server' and `text3`. Is it not printing?

Comment: `print look
        print line
        look = tooglelook(look)
print line`. it is printing same line `server` as both times

Comment: updated the answer and `code`. Is it helpful or something is still amiss

Comment: Thanks it did help me alot.a